# Property of $e^x \sin x$ composite graphs

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

Why does the composite graph of $e^x \sin x$ appear to almost be bounded (not in the mathematical sense) by the graph $e^x$ and $-e^x$? I have seen a similar thing  with the graph $e^{-x} \sin x$.

I can sketch the curve through basic analysis, but I don't see how you can deduce that it would be bounded by $e^x$?

http://ks.c.yimg.jp/res/chie-ans-233/233/320/139/i320

Comment: Excellent answers, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \sin x$ has an image of $[-1, 1]$; because it's never greater than $1$ or less than $-1$, it's never going to cause $e^x \sin x$ to be greater than $e^x$ or less than $-e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

look at the graph of $y = A\sin x$ where the amplitude $A$ is constant. we know that this graph bounces back and forth between $A$ and $-A$ for every $2\pi.$ with the graph of $y = e^x\sin x$ the envelope is not constant but changing and the graph bounces back and forth between the graphs of $e^x$ and $e({-x}.$

Answer (score 1):

This is because $$|\sin x|\leq 1 \implies |f(x)\sin x|= |f(x)|\cdot|\sin x|\leq |f(x)|\cdot 1 = |f(x)|$$ In other words, we know $$-|f(x)|\leq f(x)\sin x\leq |f(x)|$$
This is true for any function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. In your case, $e^x$ is always positive, so we can drop the absolute value bars to get
$$-e^x\leq e^x\sin x \leq e^x$$